# Get unique identifier of Exception Reason

Tags: java, android, exception

I try to change the error Output for my Android App.

What i want is something like this:

```
if (e.getCode().equals("Network is unreachable")) {

info = "error => " + "Lost Connection to Internet";

}else if(e.getCode().equals("Connection Refused")) {

info = "error => " + "Cant Reach server";
}
```

My problem is that i need a unique identifier for the Throwed error.

`e.getCode()` return: org.XXX.android.dto.core.ServiceException

So this is not a help becouse its the exception but not the reason

`e.getMessage()` return: failed to connect to /XXXX(port XXX): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

is more what i need but i only need the last part of this String like this: Network is unreachable
or another unique Reason identifier.

Thanks in advance and have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this.
A error message can be modified.
Today you return "Network is unreachable" but tomorrow you could return
any other message instead of : "Network is not reachable", "Node is unreachable", etc...

I think that `org.XXX.android.dto.core.ServiceException` is too broad.
You could have `UnreachableNetworkException` and `ConnectionRefusedException`.

Now if you want to reduce the number of specific exceptions, a better way than using String message values could be using an enum value  to specify each type of exception cases.

When you create a `ServiceException`, you could value the enum field in order to be able to reuse it in the exception handling.

For example :

```
public class ServiceException extends Exception {

    public enum Type {
        UNREACHABLE_NETWORK, CONNECTION_REFUSED;

    }

    private Type type;

    public ServiceException(String message, Exception cause, Type type) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Now you can apply the exception handling in this way :

```
if (e.getType() == ServiceException.Type.UNREACHABLE_NETWORK) {  
     info = "error => " + "Lost Connection to Internet";   
}
 else if(e.getType() == ServiceException.Type.CONNECTION_REFUSED) {    
     info = "error => " + "Cant Reach server";
}
```

Comment: Ah Thanks, i allready thought that this is not best practice. I will test it asap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
if (e.getCode().contains("Network is unreachable")) {

info = "error => " + "Lost Connection to Internet";

}else if(e.getCode().contains("Connection Refused")) {

info = "error => " + "Cant Reach server";
}
```

Just change **equals** function to **contains** function.

Comment: Works fine, but i wonder if this is best practice or just a work-around?